# org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)]

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, recursion

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    private String student_id;
    private String name;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Student_Course> studentCourses;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    private String course_id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String course_code;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Float credits;
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Student_Course {

    @EmbeddedId
    private Student_Course_PK student_course_pk;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("studentId")
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("courseId")
    private Course course;
    private Date enrollment_date;
}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class Student_Course_PK implements Serializable {

    private String studentId;
    private String courseId;
}
```

```
/* controller */

@GetMapping("/getall")
    public ResponseEntity<List<StudentDTO>> getAllStudents(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.studentService.getAllStudents());
    }

    @GetMapping("/get/{student_id}")
    public ResponseEntity<StudentDTO> getStudentById(@PathVariable String student_id){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(this.studentService.getStudentById(student_id));
    }
```

When ever I sent a request for student to get data from the database. Every time I get below error,

> "Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)] with root cause"
>
> ```
> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)] with root cause
>
> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
>   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
>   at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.prependPath(JsonMappingException.java:455) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:790) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:107) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:25) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:732) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:772) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:145) ~[jackson-databind-2.15.3.jar:2.15.3]
>   at 
> ...
> ```

I tried some of the solution. some of them are @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference, @JsonIgnore, @JsonIgnore. But it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to use `DTO` based projections and fetch just what you really need yet ?

Comment: I tried DTO but still not works.

Comment: Can you share the query that you want to execute ?

Comment: @Repository

public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, String> {

    @Query("SELECT s FROM Student s where s.student_id = :student_id")
    Optional<Student> findStudentByID(@Param("student_id") String student_id);

}

Comment: I see the problem in your design approach, in this case you have to do @ManyToMany mapping and hibernate will generate for you the mapping table. After these changes you will be able to fetch what you need without any problem.